# Cannot login to docker container registry which is inside docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab

I've got gitlab running on my localhost inside docker container. I've set up container registry for listening `localhost:4567` in file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and now I can not log in. When I write `docker login localhost:7073`(I've set mapping 7073->4567), enter my username and password, I receive:

```
Error response from daemon: Get http://localhost:7073/v1/users/: EOF
```

Comment: Make sure that your registry is listening in all of its interfaces (should be 0.0.0.0:4567)

Comment: how check that?

Comment: how did you install it? this?: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/

Comment: I use ready-made docker image of gitlab. container registry is already included to that image.